# Why does symlinks are not enabled - apache

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, symbolic-link

I have mapped my apache to the root /var/www/vhosts. 
If I put there files/folders, I see them and can surf to them.
But, If I put symlinks in /var/www/vhosts I get 403 - no permissions.
I have the following directives for this folder:

```
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are the symlinks to? What are the permissions/owner/group on these files? Do an ll on the directory above so we can see if that's the issue. When you are on the server, are you able to navigate these symlinks ok?

Comment: An `ll`?

I'm presuming you have `ll` aliased to `ls -l`.

Comment: Sorry, yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

What are the symlinks to?

What are the permissions on the data being symlinked?

What user and group does Apache run as in your config?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that apache has read permissions on the files you are trying to serve.